# How to use tf.nn.embedding_look() when the first dim of the embedding matrix will increase?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm applying the word vector model to online news articles. Since I could get new articles everyday, I won't be able to know the 'true' vocabulary size.

Say I have 10 articles now and have a vocabulary of 1000. I initialise the word embedding matrix to a shape of `[1000, emb_size]` and train the model based on the 10 articles. After this I get 1 new article which has 5 new words, so the vocabulary size becomes 1005. In order to train the model with the additional article I have to keep the old embedding matrix and add 5 new rows at the bottom, i.e. a shape of `[1005, emb_size]`.

The embedding matrix is origianly created by:

```
self.word_embedding = tf.get_variable(
    name = 'word_embedding', 
    shape = [1000, opts.embed_size], 
    initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-init_width, init_width)
)
```

I update the matrix by:

```
old_word_embedding = self.word_embedding
new_word_embedding = tf.get_variable(
    name = 'new_word_embedding', 
    shape = [5, opts.embed_size], 
    initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-init_width, init_width)
)

tf.initialize_variables([add_word_embedding]).run()

self.word_embedding = tf.Variable(tf.concat(0, [old_outside_embedding, new_outside_embedding]), name = 'word_embedding')
```

If I `print self.word_embedding.get_shape()`, it does give me the correct shape `[1005, embsize]`. However, when the model starts to train the new article, it give me an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted
```

I'm wondering if it's because this line:

`center_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.word_embedding, center)`

where `embedding_lookup` still uses the old `[1000, embed_size]` embedding matrix? If that's the case how to let it use the new `self.word_embedding`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.pad()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pad) to expand on the dimension.